# Change mocked function parameter value with FakeItEasy?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, stub, fakeiteasy

I am looking for a way to change the value of a Parameter for a Mock function with FakeItEasy.

I have something like:

```
var objParam = new ObjParam();
objParam.SomeIntValue = 0;

A.CallTo(() => iClass.Func(objParam)).WithAnyArguments().DoesNothing();
```

and I want to set the value of `objParam` for after the function is called, for example like this:

```
objParam.SomeIntValue += 1;
```

`objParam` is neither a `ref` nor a `out` Parameter, it is an object. Is there a way to do this with FakeItEasy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture the passed argument and perform the desired custom functionality

```
//Arrange
IClass iClass = A.Fake<IClass>();

A.CallTo(() => iClass.Func(A<ObjParam>._))
    .Invokes((ObjParam arg) => arg.SomeIntValue += 1);

var objParam = new ObjParam();
objParam.SomeIntValue = 0;

//Act
iClass.Func(objParam);

//Assert
objParam.SomeIntValue.Should().Be(1);
```

### Reference [Invoking Custom Code](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/invoking-custom-code/)

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the clear answer